# Get torch pad AssertionError on VITS training (TTS)

Tags: python, pytorch, text-to-speech

I was using VITS training, but get follow exception while torch padding:

```
AssertionError: 4D tensors expect 4 values for padding
```

VITS link: https://github.com/jaywalnut310/vits

VITS-japanese link: https://github.com/innnky/vits-japanese

The vesion of torch is 1.6.0 which from requirements.txt

Command: (test.json is same as nan.json from VITS-japanese)

```
python train.py -c config/test.json -m test
```

Error:

```
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 20, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/content/vits-japanese/train.py", line 117, in run
    train_and_evaluate(rank, epoch, hps, [net_g, net_d], [optim_g, optim_d], [scheduler_g, scheduler_d], scaler, [train_loader, eval_loader], logger, [writer, writer_eval])
  File "/content/vits-japanese/train.py", line 137, in train_and_evaluate
    for batch_idx, (x, x_lengths, spec, spec_lengths, y, y_lengths) in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 363, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 989, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1014, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 395, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
AssertionError: Caught AssertionError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 185, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/vits-japanese/data_utils.py", line 97, in __getitem__
    return self.get_audio_text_pair(self.audiopaths_and_text[index])
  File "/content/vits-japanese/data_utils.py", line 62, in get_audio_text_pair
    spec, wav = self.get_audio(audiopath)
  File "/content/vits-japanese/data_utils.py", line 81, in get_audio
    center=False)
  File "/content/vits-japanese/mel_processing.py", line 71, in spectrogram_torch
    y = torch.nn.functional.pad(y.unsqueeze(1), (int((n_fft-hop_size)/2), int((n_fft-hop_size)/2)), mode='reflect')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3567, in _pad
    assert len(pad) == 4, '4D tensors expect 4 values for padding'
AssertionError: 4D tensors expect 4 values for padding
```

I have trace the size of input.

original audio in data_utils.py.get_audio():

```
torch.Size([69506, 2])
```

audio_norm after unsqueeze(0) in data_utils.py.get_audio():

```
torch.Size([1, 69506, 2])
```

y.unsqueeze(1) in mel_processing.py.spectrogram_torch():

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 69506, 2])
```

the padding size was same as Default config ((1024-256)/2):

```
(384,384)
```

I didn't modify the VITS code so the tensors size and padding size should be right.

Or did I need to do something about the input wav file?

Comment: I have try fill up padding size with (0,0,384,384) but get "expected a 1D or 2D tensor of floating types" error in the next stft() line, seems input problems.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the input wav file.

It should be mono, not binaural.

I resampled the wav and it works fine.